# How to substring a string with multiple lines (no Json), without replacing them

Tags: java, string

Let's say that I have this string:

```
String test = "(\n"+
            "string 2 this is \n"+
            "string 3 this is \n"+
            "string 4 this is,\n"+";

test.substring (test.indexOf ("string 2"), (test.indexOf ("3 this");
```

This `substring` is not currently working because the new lines are in my way. Is there a way to bypass this without erasing the new lines?

The string I want is everything from string 2 to "string 3 this". I want to remove the "string 4->".

This is only an example string. I want to implement this function to a bigger project, where the strings are formatted with many lines and I want to `substring` it with `indexOf`.

Comment: Please show the string you expect to get. It isn't clear what you mean by "are in my way".

Comment: Could you show what output you are currently getting and why that isn't what you expect/want?

Comment: It's probably not working because of the last +"; Just replace +"; with ;

Comment: First of all your code doesn't compile because of `+";` at the end of string and amount of parenthesis. Second problem is that your question is still not very clear. I am trying to read it third time and I am still not sure what should be result you want since results you are describing and input which you are using has very little to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

```
String fromTo( String s, String from, String to ){
    int pos1 = s.indexOf( from );
    int pos2 = s.indexOf( to ) + to.length();
    if( pos1 < 0 || pos2 < pos1 ){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no such delimiting strings");
    }
    String res = s.substring( pos1, pos2 );
    return res;
}
```

In your example, you can call

```
String section = fromTo( test, "string 2", "string 3 this" );
```

This will contain the newlines, but you wrote "without erasing the newlines".

If you don't want to have the newlines they can easily be removed from `res`.

```
res = res.replace( "\n", "" );
```

Comment: Thank you. This works fine, but I have another string which contains newline + spaces, so when I try this code - it doesnt work because of the spaces.. and again, I cannot remove them. Any idea how to get through this?

Comment: @SandeepSingh keeps saying, "No, this isn't what I want, but I don't tell you what I want."

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you expect `indexOf` to account for the length of it's argument: it won't.

Try:

```
String limitStr = "3 this";

test.substring(test.indexOf("string 2"), test.indexOf(limitStr) + limitStr.length());
```

The result will include newlines.

A general point: always check the return value of `indexOf` against `-1` before using it.

Comment: Thank you. This works fine, but I have another string which contains newline + spaces, so when I try this code - it doesnt work because of the spaces.. and again, I cannot remove them. Any idea how to get through this?

Answer (score 0):

After fixing some compiler errors, this works quite well:

```
@Test
public void testName() throws Exception
{
    String test = "(\n"+
            "string 2 this is \n"+
            "string 3 this is \n"+
            "string 4 this is,\n"; // removed +" here

    String result = test.substring(test.indexOf ("string 2"), (test.indexOf ("3 this"))); // Added )) here and assigned the result to a variable
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

It prints

```
string 2 this is 
string
```

Comment: Thank you. This works fine, but I have another string which contains newline + spaces, so when I try this code - it doesnt work because of the spaces.. and again, I cannot remove them. Any idea how to get through this?

Comment: @SandeepSingh You keep guessing everybody what you really want. Why not add two or three examples to your question: input string is this: "...", output string should be that: "...".